# How to Change my Profile Picture With a Discord bot(Python)?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I wanted to create a bot with Python
Which Change my Avatar
I meant I want to change my profile picture in Discord With bot
please help me

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

token = 'TOKEN HERE'
pfp_path = "path/to/file.png"

fp = open(pfp_path, 'rb')
pfp = fp.read()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.user.edit(avatar=pfp)
    
client.run(token)
```

I founded this solution on: https://gist.github.com/MrLotU/b11d868243062ba9210f4994c1158d43

Comment: You should close the file or use a context manager btw

Comment: This Totally wrong this is for discord bots.
But I want to change my user profile picture